# How to replace pattern with regex using a general approach?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to replace the following pattern with regex:

```
"id": 1,"name": "A green door","price": 12.50,"tags": "green"
"id": 1,"name": "A green door","price": 12.50,"tags": "green"
"id": 1,"name": "A green door","price": 12.50,"tags": "green"
"id": 1,"name": "A green door","price": 12.50,"tags": "green"
```

and I want it to output the following:

```
1,"A green door",12.50,"green"
1,"A green door",12.50,"green"
1,"A green door",12.50,"green"
1,"A green door",12.50,"green"
```

However I want the expression to be in a general way since the values may not always be the same, the only thing that will never change is the pattern. However I have been trying different expressions like this one: `"(.*?)":`

But keep getting the wrong result. If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Can you post some of the things you have tried so we can better guide you? I would rather not just give you the answer without seeing that you have tried. (in case this is homework)

Comment: yes, I have tried the following expressions: '[^:]*, ' '("(.+?)":)|("(.+?)\") ' and a few others and discovered that the pattern is that it must have exactly two quotation marks + end in : and space but I am fairly new at regex and I am unable to input this pattern in an expression. @Duck

Comment: Rather than posting another answer myself, check out the other 2 that were given - they look like they achieve what you want. Also, check out [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) for a very helpful visual debugger next time. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pretty simple solution:

```
s/"[^"]*"\s*:\s*//g
```

If you also want to allow for backslash escapes in the strings, we can get a little more fancy:

```
s/"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"\s*:\s*//g
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** , **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** methods to get it done.

```js
var str = `"id": 1,"name": "A green door","price": 12.50,"tags": "green"
"id": 1,"name": "A green door","price": 12.50,"tags": "green"
"id": 1,"name": "A green door","price": 12.50,"tags": "green"
"id": 1,"name": "A green door","price": 12.50,"tags": "green"`;

var res = str.split('\n').map(function(v) {
  return v.split(',').map(function(v1) {
    return v1.split(':')[1].trim();
  }).join();
});

console.log(res);
```

---

Or using **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method

```js
var str = `"id": 1,"name": "A green door","price": 12.50,"tags": "green"
"id": 1,"name": "A green door","price": 12.50,"tags": "green"
"id": 1,"name": "A green door","price": 12.50,"tags": "green"
"id": 1,"name": "A green door","price": 12.50,"tags": "green"`;

var res = str.replace(/"\w+":\s*(?=.*?(?:[,|\n]|$))/g, '')

console.log(res);
```